# Horror story: only people who smoke could see some monsters

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

Decades ago I read a book (in Brazilian Portuguese, so a part may be different) about people that were able to see some monsters... but these people only saw such monsters (perhaps they would see other persons as monsters?) because they smoke. (No logic for me on that, hahah.)

I am not sure if it was a Stephen King story or not. What I do remember is that the book was actually a collection of stories. And in PT-BR it was called "Os Homens das dez horas"; in English that would be "The ten o'clock Men". Perhaps the timing would be different in English? It may happen with translations to better adapt cultural facts.

Comment: Also, it may be that the title in English is completely different?

Comment: The people who saw the batmen were in the process of quitting smoking; smokers and nonsmokers perceived the creatures as human beings.

Comment: Great @StanleyWebb! Much appreciated! All the best!

Comment: Science Fiction & Fantasy is awesome! Fast and thorough answers! Much appreciated you all!

Comment: I could see the logic working if it were something like "They're only visible as disturbances in clouds of smoke", but then it would also work with non-smokers just hanging around smokers, or possibly other visible vapors like steam, etc...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This sounds like Stephen King's "[The Ten O'Clock People](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40687)" (1993) in which people suffering from nicotine withdrawal are able to perceive some people as "batmen."

Quoting from the [plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ten_O%27Clock_People#Plot) on Wikipedia:

> Pearson, a Boston office worker, discovers that people of authority, including many police officers and political figures, including the Vice President of the United States, are **inhuman monsters disguised as people**. While on his 10 o'clock smoke break, Pearson perceives the bat-like creatures through their disguises. Noticing his reaction, a young black man named Dudley "Duke" Rhinemann stops him from screaming and calms him down. Rhinemann explains that if Pearson wants to live, he must go about his day as usual and meet him at 3 o'clock after work. Pearson does as he is told and discovers that his boss is also one of the "batmen". He leaves work a bit shaken, meets Rhinemann and goes to a bar with him. **Rhinemann explains that a unique chemical imbalance caused by nicotine withdrawal is the only way to see the creatures** and invites Pearson to a resistance meeting.

The story was translated to Portuguese as "[As Pessoas das Dez Horas](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2888666)" (2013) and published in an anthology of King's stories titled [*Pesadelos e paisagens noturnas 2*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?848797).

[image: Cover of "Pesadelos e paisagens noturnas 2"]

Comment: Certainly I just read an older Portuguese version though. Now with details I came to understand there's at least one Portuguese version from 1993, as well (ISBN: 9788573021318). Again: much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not a smoker, nor a doctor, so I apologize if this is ignorant, but why would someone be experiencing nicotine withdrawal during a smoke break? Is it that the nicotine withdrawal is what encourages the people to take smoking breaks, and they can only see the "batmen" prior to lighting up and quenching the withdrawal?

Comment: @BenHocking Pearson sees his first batman on his way out for a smoke break, _before_ he's had a smoke.  He's thinking to himself how much he wants the nicotine hit.  Subsequently the implication is that once the illusion is broken you can always see through it.

Comment: @Misael You're welcome!  ISFDb doesn't always have the best coverage for non-English works; if you feel ambitious you can try submitting the details of the earlier release you found. :)

Comment: *people who smoke* are always in withdrawal. A cigarette that's actually satisfying is few and far between, especially with this GD thick-ass paper ('fire safe') they got on 'em now. The first thing I want after a cigar is a cigarette. And after every cigarette are the wafting thoughts of when I can have another one. If you want a gateway drug, try tobacco. It doesn't need any implication; if you smoke and you're somewhere you can't smoke, your thoughts are about when and where you can go smoke, which apparently these days is ~15 feet from planet Earth.

Answer (score 9):

This is "The Ten o'Clock People" and it is indeed by Stephen King, included in his collection "Nightmares and Dreamscapes".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ten_O%27Clock_People

Answer (score 8):

A quick Google search of The Ten O'clock Men found it. In English it is "The Ten O'Clock People".

I guess the name comes from the creatures the main character sees on his 10 O'Clock smoke break.

It is a Stephen King story from the collection *Nightmares & Dreamscapes*.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ten_O%27Clock_People

Comment: Much appreciated, @CarsonNeiss! I really never thought of searching it like that hahhaha! Came up with it while asking, only (as I generally searched it in PT-BR... Appreciate you also and all for taking your time :) All the best!